# Swift understanding self[key] and casting

Tags: swift

Please consider following code:

```
extension Dictionary { 
    public func msArray(_ key: Key) -> [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
        return (self[key] as? Array<[String : Int]> ?? [])
    }
}

let dict = ["Warlock" : ["Hp" : 100],  "Rogue" : ["Hp" : 150], "Warrior" : ["Hp" : 250]]
```

Following produce []:

```
print(dict.msArray("Warlock"))
```

Why? Isn't it suppose to print `["Hp" : 100]`?

Comment: Why do you think so? `["Hp" : 100]` is not an *array* of dictionaries. – And your title is misleading, `self[key]` is not nil.

Comment: @MartinR sorry, i did edit title of my post.

Comment: Why the inconsistent syntax? You've declared the return type as `[Dictionary<String, Any>]` but you attempt to cast the return value as `Array<[String : Int]>`. Be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

It's problem with the return type.For The result you want, need to add return type as Dictionary From the extension, not an array.

Please check this code.

```
extension Dictionary {
    public func msArray(_ key: Key) -> [String : Any] {
        return self[key] as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
    }
}

let dict = ["Warlock" : ["Hp" : 100],  "Rogue" : ["Hp" : 150], "Warrior" : ["Hp" : 250]]
print(dict.msArray("Warlock"))
```

Comment: i dont want to modify function, i want to understand how it works.

Comment: okay, your main 'dict' is [String : [String: Any]] type, so using key(String) you get value from 'dict' is [String : Any] type.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You either need to modify your current function to work with the dictionary you have or you need to modify the dictionary to match the function's code.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (self[key] as? Array<[String : Int]> ?? [])
```

Here you are casting `self[key]` as an array, when it's actually a `Dictionary`, this is why it fails and the default value `[]` is returned.

You can fix it this way:

```
extension Dictionary { 
    public func msArray(_ key: Key) -> [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
        return ([self[key]] as? Array<[String : Any]> ?? [])
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the user *wants* an array to be returned, assuming this is what they want, I tried to fix it by returning an array `[self[key]]`

Answer (score 1):

`["Hp" : 100]` is a `[String : Int]` not `Array<[String : Int]>`. Thats why your `msArray` function is returning `[]`.  Change your extension to:

```
extension Dictionary { 
   public func msArray(_ key: Key) -> [String:Int]{
     return self[key] as? [String : Int] ?? [:]
   }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the return type.